# Underscore.js and noconflict

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Writing a third-party javascript code which uses `underscore.js` and tries to avoid conflicts with the *underscore.js* version that *might* be used on the main site. So, my naive code is like this:

```
window.$MyUS = _.noConflict();
```

I use `$MyUS` instead of `_` from now on. Unfortunately, on some sites I receive the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the underscore.js library included on the page?

Comment: Tried to check, haven't seen the script tag that loads the underscore so far on the page of the site. However, the line above comes from my script next to the loading of the underscore library. Am I explaining the things in a clear language please?

Comment: Can you post the part of your code that a loads underscore.js?

Comment: I am just concatenating the standard minified underscore.js file contents *as is*. And then I call `noconflict()` just as above. On most sites it works.

Comment: it looks like window.$MyUS = _.noConflict(); is being called before underscore.js has been loaded. make sure underscore.js is loaded in a separate script block above your reference. it should work then

Comment: Something must have prevented underscore.js from instantiating properly. Maybe something that loads in before it is modifying core functionality? can you ensure that the underscore.js code is the first thing to be loaded in the page?

Comment: @underscorePez: that's what I am suspecting too. I can't ensure  the loading order just because my code is third-party code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a global `exports` object defined, which prevented the *underscore.js* to be installed properly. The object has two functions declared: `compile()` and `compileToString()`. The functions' implementation reveals the `LF` object which is most likely belongs to LiveFyre Javascript API: http://www.livefyre.com/docs/javascript-sdk-reference.

That's the investigation about the unsuccessful *underscore.js* installation. Still puzzled on what shall I do now and how to resolve it properly: [underscore.js, global object named "exports" and livefyre javascript API - integration conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615610/underscore-js-global-object-named-exports-and-livefyre-javascript-api-integ).