# underscore.js, global object named "exports" and livefyre javascript API - integration conflict

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'll try to summarize a few steps and ask a question after

1. `underscore.js` failed to install when developing a 3rd-party javascript component (as described here: [Underscore.js and noconflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609415/underscore-js-and-noconflict)). my code included the following line to avoid collisions of different versions of *underscore.js*:

   window.$MyUS = _.noConflict();
2. when looking into the `underscore.js` code, it was found that if `exports` or `module.exports` is defined, than the `_` variable will become a member of `exports` or `module.exports`. It just happened (in browser, not in *Node.js* of course).
3. I've tried to save the `exports` object aside and delete it before loading `underscore.js` and restore it right after calling `noConflict()`. However, when calling `delete exports`, I've got `false`, which means that `exports` can't be deleted.
4. I've found two member functions in `exports` object: `compile()` and `compileToString()`. By looking into their implementation I've found `LF` references which perhaps refer to `livefyre` Javascript API (http://www.livefyre.com/docs/javascript-sdk-reference)

Which is the better way to resolve the conflict? I see the following options:

1. Modify the *underscore.js* code so that it won't try to install itself into `exports` object.
2. Let *underscore.js* to modify the `exports` object and hope that nothing wrong will happen on any site. In that case I will need to re-write the `window.$MyUS = _.noConflict();` line like this:

   window.$MyUS = *.noConflict || exports.*.noConflict() || ... ; // sanity checks omitted for clarity, obviously the production code must be more robust

If you need any more info - please ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer, I think, is simple: fork [underscore on GitHub](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore) and add a simple patch that refuses to attach itself to `exports` if `window` exists, and submit a pull request.

That way everyone benefits: you don't have re-apply your patch every time you upgrade your copy of underscore and others don't have to deal with that problem, either.

Comment: should the check look like `if (typeof window !== undefined) {...}`?

Comment: Well, actually the opposite. ``if(((!!module && !!module.exports) || !!exports) && typeof window === undefined) { /* CommonJS code */ }``

Comment: Thinking about it, however, it wouldn't surprise me if there's some CommonJS environment libraries for the browser, so such a change to underscore may be rejected, where they recommend that `livefyre` be changed, instead.

Comment: hence, the solution will always be maintaining a forked version, since  even in the optimistic scenario it's not feasible to assume that all the sites will immediately upgrade their livefyre versions (not speaking about other countless APIs that might behave the same)

Comment: Well, forking on GitHub will still make sense, as you can just ``git pull git@github.com/documentcloud/underscore; git push origin master`` whenever they make changes and git will keep your patch applied as long as their refactoring doesn't break it. (Which it probably won't considering underscore's relative stability.)